# Trouble getting an lmfit model to work with an integrate.quad function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, lmfit

I've defined a function that works ok to simulate some data.
For the physicists: the function should generate the Hebel-Slichter coherence peak below a superconducting transition, in NMR data.

I'd like to now fit the function to my data, using lmfit.
I'm getting an error message that seems to be because I'm using additional arguments (parameters) within the integrate.quad part of the function. I'm really not that skilled with python. Is it possible to get this working?

The code is a bit messy as I've got a section (commented out) just for plotting the data and the simulation. The code and error message are plotted below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
#import scipy.special as special
#from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from lmfit import Model

#The function that describes the change in the DOS around the Fermi-level as a function of temperature below Tc
def T1Tfunc(En, Temperature , Gamma0 , Nfactor, Gap2 , Tc):
    kB = 8.617E-5

    Delta0 = kB * Tc * Gap2 / 2
    
        
    Delta1 = Delta0 * np.tanh(((Tc / Temperature)-1) ** 0.5)
    Gamma1 = Gamma0 * (Temperature / Tc) ** Nfactor
    
    Enp = En + 8.974E-6
    
    EnB = En + Gamma1 * 1j
    EnBp = Enp + Gamma1 * 1j
    
    Ns = (EnB / np.sqrt(EnB * EnB - Delta1 * Delta1))
    Nsp = (EnBp / np.sqrt(EnBp * EnBp - Delta1 * Delta1))
    Ms = (Delta1 / np.sqrt(EnB * EnB - Delta1 * Delta1))
    Msp = (Delta1 / np.sqrt(EnBp * EnBp - Delta1 * Delta1))
    
    FE = 1/(1 + np.exp(En/(kB*Temperature)))
    FEp = 1/(1 + np.exp(Enp/(kB*Temperature)))
    
    func = (np.real(Ns)*np.real(Nsp)+np.real(Ms)*np.real(Msp))*FE*(1-FEp)
    return func

#The integration of the DOS, and resulting spin-lattice relaxation rate
def  T1T(Temperature , Gamma0 , Nfactor , Gap2 , Tc , Koringaa , Koringab): 
    kB = 8.61728E-5

    # Integration parameters
    aint = 0
    bint = 0.1

    I = integrate.quad(T1Tfunc, aint, bint, args=(Temperature , Gamma0 , Nfactor , Gap2 , Tc))[0]
#For Korringa
    return I*(2/(kB*Temperature)) * (Koringaa + Koringab * Temperature)
#For No-Korringa
#    return I*(2/(kB*Temperature)) * (Koringaa + Koringab * Tc)

T1T = np.vectorize(T1T)

#Some if functions for when the calculation values end up too small, and for above Tc
def T1Textended(Temperature , Gamma0 , Nfactor, Gap2 , Tc , Koringaa , Koringab): 
    if Temperature < (0.1 * Tc):
        T1Te = 0
    elif Temperature < Tc:
        T1Te = T1T(Temperature , Gamma0 , Nfactor , Gap2 , Tc , Koringaa , Koringab)
    else:
        T1Te = Koringaa + Koringab * Temperature
    return T1Te

T1Textended = np.vectorize(T1Textended)


#Importing some example data to be fitted

filename = 'Rb2CsC60.txt'
data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',')
datax = data[:, 0]
datay = data[:, 1]
dataerr = data[:, 2]
#print(data)

# #For plotting a simulation resulting from the function, on top of data

# #Parameters when simulating
# Tc = 32.2
# Gamma0 = 9.56496E-4
# #Gap2 = 4.18126
# Gap2 = 
# Nfactor = 1
# Koringaa = 0.02542
# Koringab = 4.24127E-4

# Temperature = np.arange((0.1 * Tc), (1.8 * Tc), (Tc / 100))
# DOST0p0 = T1Textended(Temperature , Gamma0 , Nfactor , Gap2 , Tc , Koringaa , Koringab)

# fig = plt.figure()
# ax = plt.axes()
# line1 = ax.plot(Temperature,DOST0p0)
# ax.scatter(datax,datay)

# #plt.ylim([0, 2])
# #plt.xlim([0, (2 * Tc)])

# plt.title(u"1/T_1T vs. Temperature \n \u0393\u2080 = {} eV, n = {}, T_c = {}".format(Gamma0, Nfactor, Tc))
# plt.xlabel("Temperature (K)")
# plt.ylabel("$1/(T_{1}T)$");

#Now attempting to fit the function to some data

#Define T1Textended as a function to be wrapped by the 'Model' fitting package of lmfit 
HSmodel = Model(T1Textended)

#Define and set the parameters for the model, to be fitted
params = Model.Parameters()
params.add('Tc', value=32.2, vary=False)
params.add('Gamma0', value=1E-3, vary=True)
params.add('Nfactor', value=1, vary=False)
params.add('Gap2', value=4.25, vary=True)
params.add('Koringaa', value=1, vary=True)
params.add('Koringab', value=0, vary=True)

#Check that it is read properly and gives all the right input parameters and variables
print(HSmodel.param_names, HSmodel.independent_vars)
```

Error message:

runfile('C:/Users/Ross Colman/Qsync/Hebel-Slichter/DOS_simulation/HS_fit.py', wdir='C:/Users/Ross Colman/Qsync/Hebel-Slichter/DOS_simulation')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Ross Colman\Qsync\Hebel-Slichter\DOS_simulation\HS_fit.py", line 111, in 
HSmodel = Model(T1Textended)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 277, in **init**
self._parse_params()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 489, in _parse_params
raise ValueError(f"varargs '*{fnam}' is not supported")

ValueError: varargs '*args' is not supported

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`lmfit.Model()` cannot wrap a function that is "vectorized" by `numpy.vectorize()`.

Comment: Thank you kindly. Yep, when I remove the numpy.vectorize() the lmfit.Model() part starts to work... but then it gets caught on my if/elseif/else instructions too. If I remove them just to try to get it working, then it fails because the integration.quad() needed the numpy.vectorize() to work. If you have any additional pointers on how to solve these issues I'd be vary grateful. I needed the if statements because of the discontinuity in behaviour at the superconducting transition.

Comment: @RossColman sorry, I do not understand why `vectorize` would be needed.  i would recommend peeling back some of the layers: can you call your model function `T1Textended` with reasonable parameter values in the `Temperature < Tc` range and get a sensible result?